# How to solve UserWarning: Using a target size (torch.Size([])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([1]))?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am trying to run code from a book I purchased about reinforcement learning in Pytorch. 
The code should work according to the book, but for me the model doesn't converge and the reward remains negative. It also get the following user warning:

```
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:30: UserWarning: Using a target size (torch.Size([])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([1])). This will likely lead to incorrect results due to broadcasting. Please ensure they have the same size.
```

I am a complete beginner in Pytorch, but I assume a size([]) is not a valid tensor size? I think something is going wrong in the code, but after trying to work trough it for a while, I have yet to find anything. I also messaged the book publisher some time ago, but I unfortunately did not hear back from them.

That's why I would like to ask here if anyone has ever seen this error and perhaps knows how to fix it?

The code is for implementing A2C reinforcement learning on a mountain car gym environment. I can also be found here: https://github.com/PacktPublishing/PyTorch-1.x-Reinforcement-Learning-Cookbook/blob/master/Chapter08/chapter8/actor_critic_mountaincar.py

```
'''
Source codes for PyTorch 1.0 Reinforcement Learning (Packt Publishing)
Chapter 8: Implementing Policy Gradients and Policy Optimization
Author: Yuxi (Hayden) Liu
'''

import torch
import gym
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F


env = gym.make('MountainCarContinuous-v0')


class ActorCriticModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_input, n_output, n_hidden):
        super(ActorCriticModel, self).__init__()
        self.fc = nn.Linear(n_input, n_hidden)
        self.mu = nn.Linear(n_hidden, n_output)
        self.sigma = nn.Linear(n_hidden, n_output)
        self.value = nn.Linear(n_hidden, 1)
        self.distribution = torch.distributions.Normal

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.fc(x))
        mu = 2 * torch.tanh(self.mu(x))
        sigma = F.softplus(self.sigma(x)) + 1e-5
        dist = self.distribution(mu.view(1, ).data, sigma.view(1, ).data)
        value = self.value(x)
        return dist, value


class PolicyNetwork():
    def __init__(self, n_state, n_action, n_hidden, lr=0.001):
        self.model = ActorCriticModel(n_state, n_action, n_hidden)
        self.optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.model.parameters(), lr)


    def update(self, returns, log_probs, state_values):
        """
        Update the weights of the Actor Critic network given the training samples
        @param returns: return (cumulative rewards) for each step in an episode
        @param log_probs: log probability for each step
        @param state_values: state-value for each step
        """
        loss = 0
        for log_prob, value, Gt in zip(log_probs, state_values, returns):
            advantage = Gt - value.item()
            policy_loss = - log_prob * advantage

            value_loss = F.smooth_l1_loss(value, Gt)

            loss += policy_loss + value_loss

        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        self.optimizer.step()


    def predict(self, s):
        """
        Compute the output using the continuous Actor Critic model
        @param s: input state
        @return: Gaussian distribution, state_value
        """
        self.model.training = False
        return self.model(torch.Tensor(s))

    def get_action(self, s):
        """
        Estimate the policy and sample an action, compute its log probability
        @param s: input state
        @return: the selected action, log probability, predicted state-value
        """
        dist, state_value = self.predict(s)
        action = dist.sample().numpy()
        log_prob = dist.log_prob(action[0])
        return action, log_prob, state_value




def actor_critic(env, estimator, n_episode, gamma=1.0):
    """
    continuous Actor Critic algorithm
    @param env: Gym environment
    @param estimator: policy network
    @param n_episode: number of episodes
    @param gamma: the discount factor
    """
    for episode in range(n_episode):
        log_probs = []
        rewards = []
        state_values = []
        state = env.reset()

        while True:
            state = scale_state(state)
            action, log_prob, state_value = estimator.get_action(state)
            action = action.clip(env.action_space.low[0],
                                 env.action_space.high[0])
            next_state, reward, is_done, _ = env.step(action)

            total_reward_episode[episode] += reward
            log_probs.append(log_prob)
            state_values.append(state_value)
            rewards.append(reward)

            if is_done:
                returns = []

                Gt = 0
                pw = 0

                for reward in rewards[::-1]:

                    Gt += gamma ** pw * reward
                    pw += 1
                    returns.append(Gt)

                returns = returns[::-1]
                returns = torch.tensor(returns)
                returns = (returns - returns.mean()) / (returns.std() + 1e-9)


                estimator.update(returns, log_probs, state_values)
                print('Episode: {}, total reward: {}'.format(episode, total_reward_episode[episode]))

                break

            state = next_state


import sklearn.preprocessing
import numpy as np

state_space_samples = np.array(
    [env.observation_space.sample() for x in range(10000)])
scaler = sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(state_space_samples)


def scale_state(state):
    scaled = scaler.transform([state])
    return scaled[0]


n_state = env.observation_space.shape[0]
n_action = 1
n_hidden = 128
lr = 0.0003
policy_net = PolicyNetwork(n_state, n_action, n_hidden, lr)


n_episode = 200
gamma = 0.9
total_reward_episode = [0] * n_episode

actor_critic(env, policy_net, n_episode, gamma)
```

Comment: `Size([])` is a valid size: 0 dimensions, i.e. a scalar. Which line is it that throws the warning?

Comment: Not a line from the code, but the following: `/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:30`, this is the same warning for every episode.

Answer (score 2):

size([]) is valid, but it represents a single value, not an array, whereas size([1]) is a 1 dimensional array containing only one item item. It is like comparing 5 to [5]. One solution to this is

```
            returns = returns[::-1]
            returns_amount = len(returns)
            returns = torch.tensor(returns)
            returns = (returns - returns.mean()) / (returns.std() + 1e-9)
            returns.resize_(returns_amount, 1)
```

This converts returns into a 2-dimensional array, so that each Gt you get from it will be a 1-dimensional array, not a float.